# App stopped working android

Tags: android

I don't understand why my "App" has stopped working?

This is my MainActivity.class code:-

```
package com.apps.nishant.iwillguessyournumber;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button btnplay = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cmdPlay);
    private Button btnexit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cmdExit);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        OnButtonClickListener();
    }

    public void OnButtonClickListener() {
        btnplay.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                    }
                }
        );

        btnexit.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                        adb.setMessage("Do you really wanna exit?")
                                .setCancelable(false)
                                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                })
                                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

and my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.apps.nishant.iwillguessyournumber.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cmdPlay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Play"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="147dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="219dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cmdExit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Exit"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="147dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="328dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Whenever I am running this app on Genymotion Android:6.0.0 and API 23, it is showing "Unfortunately, (app name) is not working"

What is the problem in my code/platform?

I've tried restarting my apps, looked up a few questions but couldn't yet get my answer when I open a new Activity using Intent, the second activity can't parse the xml file.

Comment: A stacktrace would be really helpful here

Comment: please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Post your stack trace when asking for help on crashes.  Otherwise we're guessing what the problem is, and there may even be more than one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of your app crash is the following 2 lines,

```
private Button btnplay = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cmdPlay);
private Button btnexit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cmdExit);
```

The method findViewById() should be called inside the onCreate() after the setContentView(). The following code should work,

```
package com.apps.nishant.iwillguessyournumber;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button btnplay;
    private Button btnexit;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnplay = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cmdPlay);
        btnexit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cmdExit);
        OnButtonClickListener();
    }

    public void OnButtonClickListener() {
        btnplay.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                    }
                }
        );

        btnexit.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                        adb.setMessage("Do you really wanna exit?")
                                .setCancelable(false)
                                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                })
                                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```